# Firestore set function not doing anything (React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get some info from the facebook profile after using FB Login and store it in my users collection on firestore. Using this snippet inside the facebook successful callback:

```
var userDict = {
              id: user.uid,
              fullname: user.displayName,
              email: user.email,
              profileURL: user.photoURL + "?type=large"
            };
            var data = {
              ...userDict,
              appIdentifier: "foodwaste"
            };
            ref
              .doc(user.uid)
              .get()
              .then(docSnapshot => {
                if (!docSnapshot.exists) {
                  this.ref.doc(user.uid).set(data);
                }
              });
```

my ref is `const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users");` I am sure the get function works as I get back a snapshot and it goes into the if statement after that nothing happens no error and the database does not get updated. This used to work normally before and I have been trying to find out why it suddenly doesn't for ages! Would appreciate any help thank you.

Comment: You might want to add a `catch((err) => console.error(err)` after the `then()` to see of that shows any problems.

Comment: is you function entering in the if condition?

`if (!docSnapshot.exists) {
                  this.ref.doc(user.uid).set(data);
                }`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys, @FrankvanPuffelen I did and no errors come up.

Comment: @JorgeHernandez It does enter the if yes I tested it with console.log

Comment: Is your code able to push userdata by using a simple insertion?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#add_data